# UIImagePicker on ipad simulator not full width

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ipad

When viewing an image in a UIImagePicker on the iPad (using the simulator ios9) the selected image from the library is very small (see iPad example below). Now if the same image is selected on other devices (iPhone 5 .6 .6Plus) the selected image is always full screen (see below). 
I have an iPad2 (non retina) and if I run my app on this device the image in a UIImagePicker is full size like on the iPhone.
So is this only a problem when running the iPad simulator?

[image]

I need the image to be full width like on the iPhone

[image]

Comment: Test on a device and check once, if you can

Comment: I have only got an old iPad - need to know if newer iPads display the image full screen.

Comment: yes they do as far as i know

Comment: Just found out that when you use iPad simulator for iOS 8.1 the image is full screen (correct) but when using iPad simulator for iOS 9.0 the image is tiny and when saved (without cropping) the image is cropped. Still don't know if this is what happens on actual iPad device ??  It would be great if someone could confirm on an actual iPad running iOS 9

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is a bug in iOS 9 not yet resolved

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19999

I would recommend to develop a custom crop view controller